# google analytics core api results sampling level

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I have a script pulling data from the Google Analytics core api. Since I am using the results of the data to successfully populate a sheet in GSheets I know that my data pull is a success.

I'm reading the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference).

In particular, this table:
[image]

However, I would like to Logger.log() the sampling level of the query:

```
// check sampling for each report
    if(!results.containsSampledData) {
      Logger.log('sampling: none');
    } else {
      Logger.log('sampling: ' + results.query.samplingLevel);
    }
```

When I view the logs I get 'sampling: undefined'.

How do I get the sampling results from the results object?

Here is what generates the results object, though I don;t think it's relavant (but may be wrong):

```
// get GA data from core api
function getReportDataForProfile(profile, len_results, start_num) {
  var startDate = getLastNdays(30); // set date range here
  var endDate = getLastNdays(0);

  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions': 'ga:dimension5, ga:dimension4', // Comma separated list of dimensions.
    'start-index': start_num,
    'max-results': len_results,
    'filters': 'ga:source==cj'
  };

      // Make a request to the API.
      var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get( // mcf for multi channel api, Ga for core
          profile,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
          startDate,                  // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
          endDate,                    // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
          'ga:goalCompletionsAll, ga:users, ga:sessions', // Comma seperated list of metrics.
          optArgs);

      return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed this sentence:

> The following table summarizes all the query parameters accepted by
>   the Core reporting API.

Those are query parameters. In other words, values that YOU supply. So, you should already know what the sampling level is since you determine it.

[Here's the doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#samplingLevel) on sampling level. If not supplied, it sets samplingLevel to DEFAULT.

**EDIT:** [Here's the doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#data_response) on the response. I see that it indeed includes a samplingLevel field, but if you scroll further down, samplingLevel isn't one of the fields described in the Response Fields table. I suspect it is either included in the response by accident or you cannot rely upon that field given the lack of documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried to paste my answer as a comment to your answer but was too big. Might just delete. But basically the info I needed was results.sampleSize/results.sampleSpace

Answer (score 1):

Ah. If I read further down I would have seen this paragraph:

> Sampling
>
> Google Analytics calculates certain combinations of dimensions and
>   metrics on the fly. To return the data in a reasonable time, Google
>   Analytics may only process a sample of the data.
>
> You can specify the sampling level to use for a request by setting the
>   samplingLevel parameter.
>
> If a Core Reporting API response contains sampled data, then the
>   containsSampledData response field will be true. In addition, 2
>   properties will provide information about the sampling level for the
>   query: sampleSize and sampleSpace. With these 2 values you can
>   calculate the percentage of sessions that were used for the query. For
>   example, if sampleSize is 201,000 and sampleSpace is 220,000 then the
>   report is based on (201,000 / 220,000) * 100 = 91.36% of sessions.
>
> See Sampling for a general description of sampling and how it is used
>   in Google Analytics."

So to get sample size as a percentage (what I'm used to seeing) I do this: results.sampleSize/results.sampleSpace